# Wraping a p-column in a custom directive

Tags: angular, primeng

I'm new to angular and trying to get a piece of code more precise. I'm using the dataTable from primeNG and have to add a lot of custom formatting to each column.

```
<p-dataTable id="tsd" [value]="employeeData.workPrograms" *ngIf="employeeData" [responsive]="true" >
    <p-column header="{{getDayFormatted(0)}}" [style]="{'width':'50px'}">
        <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                <div>formatted column header</div>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template let-ta="rowData" let-i="rowIndex" pTemplate="body">
            <div class="timesheetCell">
                <div class="timesheetCellData">{{ta.day1}}</div>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </p-column>
    <p-column header="{{getDayFormatted(1)}}" [style]="{'width':'50px'}">
        <ng-template pTemplate="header">
                <div>formatted column header</div>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template let-ta="rowData" let-i="rowIndex" pTemplate="body">
            <div class="timesheetCell">
                <div class="timesheetCellData">{{ta.day2}}</div>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

The above works, but I'll have a week or two worth of columns, this could get into the hundereds of lines when all I really want to do is change the day data for each column.  I'd like to be able to do something like:

```
<p-dataTable id="tsd" [value]="employeeData.workPrograms" *ngIf="employeeData" [responsive]="true" >
    <workDayColumn  [dayData]="rowData.day1" [dayOfPayPeriod]="0" ></workDayColumn>
    <workDayColumn [dayData]="rowData.day2" [dayOfPayPeriod]="1" ></workDayColumn>
</p-dataTable>
```

Hiding all the repetitive code in a custom directive.

I recognize that this method is all kinds of wrong, like rowData not being defined at the time the tag is read, and the tag not being recognized as a valid child of p-dataTable in the first place.

Is there some simple solution to this kind of problem? Starting to think it might be easier to just build my own table rather than use a pre-made component.